# For loop skips straight to the end

Tags: c#, for-loop

I started studying C# and I encountered a problem with one of my assignments. The assignment is to create a pyramid made of stars. The height is designated by user input.

For some reason my first `for` loop skips to the end. While debugging, I noticed that the variable `height` receives `bar`'s value, but after that it skips to the end. I have no clue why, as the code seems fine to me.

The `do`-`while` loop is there to ask the user for a new value, in case the value entered is `0` or lower.

```
using System;

namespace Viope
{
    class Vioppe
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int bar; 

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");
                string foo = Console.ReadLine();
                bar = int.Parse(foo);
            }
            while (bar <= 0);

            for (int height = bar; height == 0; height--)
            {
                for (int spaces = height; spaces == height - 1; spaces--)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (int stars = 1; stars >= height; stars = stars * 2 - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want `height >= 0`. your `for` loop doesn't even start because the condition is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition in a `for` loop is the condition which has to keep being *true* in order to go into the loop body. So this:

```
for (int height = bar; height == 0; height--)
```

should be:

```
for (int height = bar; height >= 0; height--)
```

Otherwise, the assignment is performed, then it will check whether `height` is 0, and if it's not (which is bound to be the case), that's the end of the loop.

See the [MSDN documentation for `for` loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
for (int height = bar; height >= 0; height--)
```

instead of

```
for (int height = bar; height == 0; height--)
```

Answer (score 2):

The while loop is only exited when bar is less than or equal to zero. So initially in the for loop height = bar (which is greater than 0). THen you check if height is equal to zero, and this is false. You want to check >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int height = bar; height == 0; height--)
```

Your condition:  `height == 0;`  will **never** be true.

In order for it to be true, height must be `0`,
and in order for height to be `0`, bar must be `0`.

If `bar` was `0`, than you wouldn't even have gotten to your for loop because of this infinite while loop:

```
while (bar <= 0);
```